# JavaFX how to change user Clicked button color

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

How can I change the Clicked Button background colour?. and if when user clicks on an another button. how to change the previously selected button colour to default and change the newly clicked button.

### example

there are two buttons A and B and they have default styles.
When a user clicks on Button A I want to change its colour and next if the user clicked on Button B I want do same thing as button A but after that I want to change the color of Button A to default color because now the clicked button is B

Comment: What do you mean by "selected" in this context? A [`Button`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) does not have a `selected` property.

Comment: Yha it&#39;s not a property.i am asking if user click on the button then need to change the color.anyway if there was a property called selected i may implement it easily &#128578;&#128513;

Comment: so what do you mean by "selected'? There's no notion of selection for a button, unless you are referring to a `ToggleButton`.

Comment: okay i will edit my bad the question "selected" to "clicked" :)

Comment: how about now???

Comment: Why don't you just use a `ToggleButton`?

Comment: more than 2 buttons

Comment: Then use more than 2 `ToggleButton`s, in the same `ToggleGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this via css, a Button has a focused and [ressed css selectors

```
.button:default:hover:pressed,
.button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: might or not be a solution, depending on what the OP really wants - which s/he preferred not to tell us :)

Comment: I went literal with button clicked (selected) background color... we can only try to help off the information provided to us

Comment: true, but it's always an option to _not_ answer an unanswerable question :)

Comment: that is something I definitely need to learn.  You've saved me more than a few times by closing a question, and I appreciate you for that